# Randomly change background color on button click?

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);


    final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);
    n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random RAND=new Random();
            String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
            tv.setText(nextValue);
        }
    });
}
```

I also have this:

```
<string-array name="colorcode_array">
<item>3498db</item>
<item>2ecc71</item>
<item>9b59b6</item>
<item>f1c40f</item>
<item>1abc9c</item>
<item>2980b9</item>
<item>8e44ad</item>
<item>e41c1c</item>
<item>2ecca9</item>
<item>752ecc</item>
<item>4f2ecc</item>
<item>2eccc3</item>
<item>2ecc53</item>
<item>2ecc2e</item>
<item>5bcc2e</item>
<item>9ecc2e</item>
<item>cca12e</item>
<item>cc712e</item>
<item>f1c209</item>
<item>86f109</item>
<item>f11616</item>
<item>9c1818</item>
</string-array>
```

Now what I would need is that the moment the button is clicked, you can see that the button already randomley loads text into the textview from things_array, but at the same time I want the background color to change randomly by using the color codes in colorcode_array.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+array[index]));` should do it for you :)

(your case: `view = tv` and `array[index] = nextValue`

Comment: This would work, but i want all the colors from the string-array in randomized order

Comment: That is exaxtly what I mean. `string` = `"#"+array[index]`

Comment: Sorry for my noobness... So like this: #+colorcode_array[index]  ?

Comment: of course you need to have `tv` instead of view and `"#"+nextValue` instead of "#"+array[index]

Comment: It crashes when i click the button. Is that because the array in that onclick method is things_array, which is text not color codes, and because tv is textview, and the textview doesnt have a background color?

Comment: If I wasn't clear, the background color of the activity must change not the textview's